# Error al conectarme a mysql desde Symfony

Tags: mysql, symfony

Utilizo el comando `php bin/console doctrine:database:create` y me da este error.

```
In AbstractMySQLDriver.php line 93:

  An exception occurred in driver: SQLSTATE[HY000] [1045] Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password:
  YES)


In PDOConnection.php line 31:

  SQLSTATE[HY000] [1045] Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: YES)


In PDOConnection.php line 27:

  SQLSTATE[HY000] [1045] Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: YES)
```

mi archivo .env está así:

```
###> doctrine/doctrine-bundle ###
# Format described at http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-dbal/en/latest/reference/configuration.html#connecting-using-a-url
# For an SQLite database, use: "sqlite:///%kernel.project_dir%/var/data.db"
# Configure your db driver and server_version in config/packages/doctrine.yaml
DATABASE_URL=mysql://root:admin1234@127.0.0.1:3306/advSoftware
###< doctrine/doctrine-bundle ###
```

Lo he probado tambien así:
`DATABASE_URL="mysql://root:admin1234@127.0.0.1:3306/advSoftware"`

Utilizo Symfony y en http://localhost/phpmyadmin puedo entrar con normalidad con el user 'root' y contraseña 'admin1234'

He intentado el user 'admin' sin contraseña y me da este error:

```
Could not create database `advSoftware` for connection named default
An exception occurred while executing 'CREATE DATABASE `advSoftware`':

SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1044 Access denied for user ''@'localhost' to database 'advsoftware'
```

[image: imagen con los usarios que tengo]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

He puesto el user root en .env y le he puesto que no tenía contraseña y se ha creado correctamente la bbdd